# QT OpenGL not fully rendering cube?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, rendering, opengl-compat

I am trying to create and display a 3D square but for some reason when I render it, parts of it are missing:

```
void DrawCube::drawCubes(int amount){ 



      glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.0,  1);
        glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.0, -1);
        glVertex3f( 1.0,  1.0, -1);
        glVertex3f( 1.0,  1.0,  1);
        glEnd();


      glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, -1);
        glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.0, -1);
        glVertex3f( 1.0,  1.0, -1);
        glVertex3f(-1.0,  1.0, -1);
      glEnd();


      glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(-1.0, -1.0, 1);
        glVertex3f( 1.0, -1.0, 1);
        glVertex3f( 1.0,  1.0, 1);
        glVertex3f(-1.0,  1.0, 1);
      glEnd();


      glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f( -1.0, -1.0,  1);
        glVertex3f( -1.0, -1.0, -1);
        glVertex3f( -1.0,  1.0, -1);
        glVertex3f( -1.0,  1.0,  1);
      glEnd();
  }
```

}

[image: rendering problem]

I'm not looking for answers that just give me the code, but rather an explanation as to what causes this thanks.

Comment: That is not the original code, isn't it? Where does the lighting come from, without normal vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cube seems to be clipped by the far plane of the projection. Increase the distance to the far plane, when you set the projection matrix by [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml).
Note, the projection matrix defines a view volume (see [3D projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection)). All the geometry which is out of the viewing volume is clipped.